# Atmel ICE Debugger - Does it work with nRF52-DK

Tags: atmel, debugging

I bought the Full Kit Atmel ICE (2016) to allow me to debug AVR chips. The Atmel ICE debugger can program both AVR as well as SAM for ARM Cortex. I have an Nordic Semiconductors nRF52-DK board which has an 64MHz ARM Cortex-M4F processor. **Could I use the ICE kit to debug this development kit or is it locked to work only with Atmel Cortex chips?** Will I have to buy another debugger kit? If so which will work with the nRF52-DK board?

Comment: Microcontroller Manufacturers' programmers and ICE are almost always locked to their products. I don't know for a fact that no one has made the Atmel ICE work with an nRF52-DK, but I would be amazed, and I would expect that it is not supported by Atmel. The rest of your question can be solved using a web search. For example, I looked at the nordic web site, where it says "Program/Debug options on the kit is Segger J-Link OB". However, it is 'mbed enabled' which almost always means it has an on-board debugger already and you don't need another. Read the documentation, and that should be clear

Comment: @gbulmer thanks... on-board debugger makes sense. I did not know that was present.

Answer (score 2):

just test it with OpenOCD and Atmel ICE via CMSIS-DAP - and it's working fine.

```
c:\_elektro\OpenOCD>bin\openocd.exe -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg  -f target/nrf52.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0 (2019-02-10) [https://github.com/sysprogs/openocd]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
cortex_m reset_config sysresetreq
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : CMSIS-DAP: SWD  Supported
Info : CMSIS-DAP: JTAG Supported
Info : CMSIS-DAP: FW Version = 01.27.0082
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Serial# = J41800069538
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface Initialised (SWD)
Info : SWCLK/TCK = 1 SWDIO/TMS = 1 TDI = 1 TDO = 1 nTRST = 0 nRESET = 1
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface ready
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x2ba01477
Info : nrf52.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Info : accepting 'telnet' connection on tcp/4444
Warn : target was in unknown state when halt was requested
Info : nRF52832-QFAA(build code: B0) 512kB Flash
```

Comment: Yes, sometimes this works.  But don't count on it.  I found one firmware version of the atmel probe could program stm32's while another that had been connected to a Windows box with Atmel software and received a firmware update no longer could.